# django two digit integer in choice field

Tags: python, django

I have a form that I want to submit date as `mm/yyyy`.

```
class Add_Serv(forms.Form):
   month_add = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=['01','02'])
   year_add = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, 
              choices=[(x, x) for x in xrange(date.today().year - 1, date.today().year + 1)])
```

When my month prints out in form, it's only one digit integer `1` instead of `01`. It doesn't sound like a big deal but it screws up my date format when handling these dates (and also looks very ugly). Is there any way to keep that zero before the number?

Answer (score 1):

add validation in form's clean method and check if the length of month field is 1 or 2.
Append 0 before if length is 1 and return value of month

Comment: yes. I'd do it in `clean_month_add` see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/)

Answer (score 1):

Print it out using `format`:

```
print("{:02d}".format(my_number))
```

See [Pyformat](http://pyformat.info/) for more formatting tips

Answer (score 0):

use jquery library

You need only one field.
forms.py

```
class FormA(forms.Form):
    fecha = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%m/%Y'])
```

views.py

```
def formulario(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FormA(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            # action
    else:
        form = FormA()
    return render(request,"add.html",{'form':form})
```

Your template 
I add bootstrap css library and django-bootstrap-from

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <form id="form" action="" method="POST">
            {{form|bootstrap_horizontal}}
            {%csrf_token%}
            <p align="right"><button id="enviar" type= 'submit' class="btn btn-success"> Guardar</button>
            <button type= "reset" class="btn btn-warning"> Limpiar</button></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#id_fecha').datepicker( {
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
    }
</style>
```

The result
http://prntscr.com/7qd01v